# Как создать свою библиотеку в composer?

Tags: php, github, composer

Есть такая библиотека как PHPExcel, на данный момент её нельзя подключить через composer (package of any version not found), скачал её напрямую с github.

Как можно её загрузить так, чтобы можно было использовать через composer? Т.е. загрузить в свое хранилище, репозиторий, нужен ли для этого аккаунт на github? 
Искал в гугле, практически на всех сайтах инструкция: команда `php composer.phar init` а дальше по инструкции, вот на этом моменте как раз и непонятно всё.

P.S. Я новичок с composer и github, не судите строго.

Answer (score 2):

Библиотека [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) устарела и не поддерживается. Сейчас используется [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet), которая прекрасно ставиться через composer

Comment: А что делать если PhpSpreadsheet не подходит по системным требованиям, для этой библиотеки нужен php > 5.6, а на проекте 5.5?

Comment: http://joxi.net/BA06V1JiJZxVQm - и все эти пакеты нужно подключать?

Comment: Да нужны эти пакеты. Если PHPExcel, то просто скачайте и разместите в проекте, сделайте загрузку классов и используйте без composer.

Comment: Использовать библиотеку без composer, когда в проекте все подключается через composer признак плохого тона и говнокода, поэтому даже не знаю.

Comment: Есть смысл перейти тогда на php 5.6 :)

Answer (score 0):

> PHPExcel, на данный момент её нельзя подключить через composer

Почему нельзя? Когда композер не находит пакет в своем репозитории, он ищет его на гитхабе. Вот только что на сервере установил PHPExcel командой:

```
composer require PHPOffice/PHPExcel
```